# Screen sharing MacBook-pro to iMac

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, ssh, screen, screen-sharing

I wonder if there is someway of sharing the screen on my macbook pro (which stands on the right of my iMac) to the iMac, so that I can use the same keyboard and mouse for both computers. 
I believe there was someway of doing this between windows and linux a few years ago using a kind of SSH-tunnel, but cannot find the application or what its called.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Teleport](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14042/teleport) (free)

This application allows you to use exactly what you have described; the mouse is 'teleported' to the other screen when moving to its edge. It finds computers using Bonjour and sends events over TCP. Note that it is a preference pane utility (found in System Preferences).

Answer (score 7):

### Screen Sharing

Screen sharing is actually built-in already. Enable "Screen Sharing" in System Preferences -> Sharing on the computer you want to access remotely. Then you can access it from the Finder either by selecting it in the sidebar window or directly via <kbd>Cmd-K</kbd> and entering the address `vnc://IP-Address` or `vmc://Bonjour Name.local`.

Answer (score -2):

If you've got an iCloud account, the easiest way to share a screen on Mac is to use Back to My Mac which is part of OS X and free. It can be a bit tricky to setup the first time you use it but once it's done, it's very convenient. Alternatively, there are plenty of [free screen sharing apps for Mac](https://machow2.com/rdp-for-mac/) that allow you to connect to any Mac anywhere and share the screen such as TeamViewer and LogMeIn. Hope it helps!